# How to name ADO connection while creating it in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ado

How to name ADO connection with VBA? Using ADO method of the following VBA code adds new connection which is named by default "Connection" or "Connection2" etc.

```
Sub Make_ADO_Connection()
Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents

Dim oCn As ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnString As String
Dim SQL As String

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
Debug.Print ConnString

Set oCn = New ADODB.Connection
oCn.ConnectionString = ConnString
oCn.Open

SQL = "select asdf1,asdf2,asdf5 from [Arkusz1$] where asdf1 is not null"

Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
oRS.Source = SQL
oRS.ActiveConnection = oCn
oRS.Open

'-------------------
'Here new connection is established with a name "Connection", I want to use a different name for it.
Set objListObject = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
Source:=oRS, LinkSource:=True, _
TableStyleName:=xlGuess, Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A1"))
objListObject.Refresh

If oRS.State <> adStateClosed Then
oRS.Close
End If

If Not oRS Is Nothing Then Set oRS = Nothing
If Not oCn Is Nothing Then Set oCn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I would like to name new ADO connection while creating it i.e. "MyConnectionName" checking earlier if such a connection exists.

**Edit.** I can loop through the connections:

```
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    Debug.Print conn.Name 'This name I want to set up
Next conn
```

I know that the connection with name "Connection" is created with this statements:

```
Set objListObject = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
Source:=oRS, LinkSource:=True, _
TableStyleName:=xlGuess, Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A1"))

objListObject.Refresh
```

Comment: What do you mean 'name ADO connection'? Do you mean how to name to object?

Comment: @Gareth probably yes, please check for Edit of my question.

Comment: I'm confused - I don't see how any of the answers in the linked thread could create a data connection in your workbook.

Answer (score 1):

To Create a connection to a DB with ADO use something like this:

```
Public Sub TestQueryInvokation()

Dim oCnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim oCmd As New ADODB.Command

oCnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\TestDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCnn
oCmd.CommandText = "Query1"
Call oCmd.Execute

End Sub
```

This is different from the connection stuff you're looking at there. 
If you import data using the Excel ribbon it creates a connection and maintains a link to the DB and puts it in that collection you've shown. I've experienced problems with this approach in the past and would recommend you create your own.

You need a reference to the ADO library. Alternatively type everything as Object and you'll not need the reference.

Comment: (1) How to assign other parameters to your style connection? They are the same? I mean the SQL string, OpenRowset etc? (2) Can you please give an example of "typing everything as Object" - this is particularly interesting.

Comment: By the way, this is the same for your example of using Excel like a DB. Use an ADO class and no need to refresh any links etc.

Comment: The example shows how to connect for an update type query. You've already defined the connection string in your example for use the ACE driver. So in you're code, after you open the recordset use something like CopyFromRecordSet to copy to the range and then close the recordset. Don't use what you have after this w.r.t. Connection collections.

Comment: What about typing the Object?

Comment: My code is used only once to generate the results of SQL statement. I do not need this connection to persist. Actually I want to name the connection to delete it after the ListObject table is generated. Your code looks very elegant but I want ADO connection for Insert query, not update.

Comment: All the objects in you example are typed. i.e. you have defined ...As ADODB.Connection etc. So as they are now, they are correctly typed. If you want to late bind the objects, you could declare them ... As Object instead. This will late bind the object and not require the explicit reference. Early binding is preferred if possible since you can catch compilation errors and use events. I only late bind if necessary.

Comment: Can you please rewrite macro in your answer declaring Objects. One example is worth hundred words.

Comment: Public Sub TestQueryInvokation()

Dim oCnn As Object 
Dim oCmd As Object 

set oCnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

oCnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\TestDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCnn
oCmd.CommandText = "Query1"
Call oCmd.Execute

End Sub

Comment: If you press the '.' after oCnn for example, you won't see any type information because you are now late bound. When you are late bound you effectively bypass the compiler checking and can potentially move a compilation error to a run time error which should be avoided if possible. I'd recommend trying to go early bound in the majority of cases - if possible.